# For how many points in a game volleyball is played?

Tags: rules, scoring, volleyball

In volleyball how many points to be win normally by a team to take that game?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question answered directly by the rules of the sport; Stack Exchange is not a lookup service or a search engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal rules are 25 points (a margin of 2 is required, so 25-24 will not win a set, but 26-24 will), and 15 points for the final set (the *game* is won after winning three sets, it's a best-of-five system). Theoretically, you can win a game with only 65 points (e.g. 25-20, 25-20, 0-25, 0-25, 15-10), but in practice 75 (winning 3-0 in sets) is the minimum.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volleyball#Scoring) lists the standard rules; some competitions, especially at the lower levels of play, play fewer sets or even fewer points in a set.